# Unable to target button that has no control with pywinauto

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I have a problem trying to click a button (which is not actually a button control) in a ClickOnce application I'm automating. It's located in "ViewManager1 pane" according to Inspect.exe, but there are no children of this pane and no controls. Looks like this:

[image: ViewManager1 pane]

The only thing I've been able to come up with is using the pywinauto.mouse.click function with coords. However, I don't always know the size of the window. I can maximize the window and click it, but I would like to be able to find the coords regardless of the window size. The problem is the button I want (Active Directory) may be left of center or right of center depending on the window's size.

More acceptable would be to resize the window (instead of maximize) and then click the coords, but I can't figure out how to resize it. The window's actions from Inspect.exe are as follows:

[image: Actions]

Window.SetVisualState only allows Minimize, Maximize, or Normal. I thought about calling .rectangle.mid_point() to get the center coords of the pane, but I don't know how to find the button from there since it moves based on window's size.

Is there any way that I can find the coords of the Active Directory button, or alternatively resize the window?